# How to use local variables in muttrc

Tags: mutt, neomutt

I'm interested to know if it is possible to assign and use local variables in muttrc. For instance, let's say I have credentials in some file. I'll read this file as is, e.g.

```
set creds=`cat file`
```

and, then I would like to use `$creds` within my muttrc file for further processing, e.g.

```
set my_var=`head -1 $creds`
set my_foo=`tail -1 $creds`
```

Is it possible, and, if so, what is correct syntax (the one I shown above does not work for me)?

Answer (score 1):

You were close.

mutt is able to "source" files that contain configuration commands. It's similar to when you make a change to a file like `.bashrc` and want to read the changes into your current login with `source ~/.bashrc`. Basically, you're telling mutt to load an additional configuration file and process it before continuing on with processing your primary `muttrc`.

The *insecure* version of what you want to do is to make a file called `creds` that looks something like this:

```
set imap_user=me@example.com
set imap_pass=mysecretpassword
```

Then source that file in your main `.muttrc`:

`source ~/.mutt/creds # or wherever you put it`

When mutt is loading and gets to that line, it'll read that file and process it as if it were part of a `muttrc` file,  then it'll continue on to the next line in your `.muttrc`.

However, this approach means your passwords are sitting around in plaintext, which is not a best practice. So you can stop there and live with the risks (accidentally checking into version control, for instance) or you can improve the situation with gpg:

First, encrypt your `creds` file with gpg, e.g. `gpg -r yourgpgid@example.com --encrypt creds`. That will give you an encrypted file called `creds.gpg`.

Second, change your `.muttrc` to decrypt that file when you first run mutt by replacing the line where you sourced `creds` with this one:

`source "gpg -d ~/.mutt/creds.gpg |"`

When you first run mutt, you'll get a password prompt to authenticate in gpg key, the file will be decrypted, and mutt will set the `imap_user` and `imap_pass` configuration variables before moving on to process the rest of `muttrc`.

(Once you have this working, don't forget to delete the unencrypted `creds` file.)

You could put just your password in there, but using `source` is useful for keeping your `muttrc` simple if you use mutt with multiple accounts, so you can make a `creds.work`, `creds.personal`, etc. It's also great for storing discrete account configs. I tend to follow the pattern:

```
personal.profile
  -> personal.credentials
  -> personal.sig
work.profile
  -> work.credentials
  -> work.sig
```

The `foo.profile` files contain all the configuration directives for a given account, such as `set signature = ~/.mutt/personal.sig`, `set realname = "John Doe`"` server variables, mailboxes, etc.

Macros can switch from one account to the other:

```
macro index .cp '<sync-mailbox><enter-command>source ~/.mutt/personal.profile<enter><change-folder>!<enter>'

macro index .cw '<sync-mailbox><enter-command>source ~/.mutt/iterable.profile<enter><change-folder>!<enter>'
```

So if I'm in the index of my personal account and want to switch to my work account, I tap `.cw` (for "change to work") and that sources my `work.profile` account, which in turn sources the signature and decrypts my work credentials. When I want to switch back, I tap `.cp` (for "change to personal") and it sources my `personal.profile` which then sources all the supporting files for that account.

Using `source` is a good way to break a long `muttrc` into logical pieces, such as macros, scores, colors, etc. and it makes it easier to make variants for multiple profiles/accounts by just tacking on the `.work` or `.personal` extension and sourcing them from the main `foo.profile` file.

My main `muttrc` just sets the things all the accounts should have in common, such as the cache directory, general configuration (`date_format`, `index_format`, `attribution`), and it pulls in my default profile with `source ~/.mutt/personal.profile`.